# Unable to split a conjunction in Hypothesis

Tags: coq, formal-languages

I have the following Hypothesis:

```
ls: list(R)

H: forall n : nat,
     0 <= INR n < 10 ->
     My_first_condition n
     /\forall x : R,
      In x ls ->
      My_second_condition x
```

What I would like to achieve is to be able to split H as two conditions:

```
ls: list(R)

H1: forall n : nat,
     0 <= INR n < 10 ->
     My_first_condition n

H2: forall x : R,
    In x ls ->
    My_second_condition x
```

To do this, I tried to use `destruct H` but I got the following error:

```
Unable to find an instance for the variables n.
```

Does anyone know why it happens and what would be a solution ?

Answer (score 4):

You need parentheses around the `forall`:

```
(forall n : nat, ...) /\
(forall x : R, ...)
```

Right now, Coq interprets what you wrote as

```
forall n : nat, (
  ... /\ forall x : R, ...
)
```